# Как передать двумерный массив в функцию?

Tags: c++

Два массива разного размера передаём в функцию для дальнейшей обработки

```
void proc(...) {
//цикл пересчёта для массивов разного размера
   if (M[a][b] < 0) {
     ....
   }
  }

int main() {
  X[x1][x2];
  Y[y1][y2];
  proc(X , x1, x2);
  proc(Y , y1, y2); //x1,x2,y1,y2 нужны для цикла 
 }
```

Если кто понял что я пытался спросить, помогите пожалуйста :3

Comment: Передавайте адрес начала и 2 размерности -- `proc(&X[0][0], x1, y1);` А функции обращайтесь к `X` как к одномерному массиву -- `void proc (T *M, int x1, int x2) { ... if (M[a * x2 + b] < 0) { ... }}` Т.е. выбирая индекс элемента `M[a][b]` считаете сколько элементов будет в `a` строках и прибавляете номер элемента в строке.

Comment: Или то же самое(но выглядит лучше)   proc(X[0], x1, y1) ;     X[i]  является указателем на i - тую строку. Сама функция будет принимать указатель на целое

Answer (score -2):

Можно, например так

```
void proc(int **M, int x, int y){
  ...
},
```

где x и y - размеры массива.

Comment: а вы попробуйте туда передать  двумерный массив  (не динамический), например int  N[2][3]. Вы не сможете присвоить указателью на указатель  двумерный массив.